# Mass Deploy same code to Heroku individual accounts

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I want to set a business model where I Mass deploy same code base(Python Django with Postgres) to my customers heroku accounts .

(I want customers to manage their own accounts and for me to stay only as software provider.However customers should  get a SaaS experience without me actually having to take care of multitenant details.Also customers will be able to freeze at any time and get out of the upgrade process or to switch to custom code)

So customer will purchase my software and setup the heroku account . I will get  credentials from customer and add it to my deployment process and the code will be deployed each time to all the accounts for  bugs fixes and for new versions.

Do you think it is possible to  achieve with Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and actually it is really easy to do IHMO.

The simplest method would be to just get credentials for each account and do git push. But a better way is to use Heroku api. You can first deploy new version to your own app which will give you a compiled slug that you can then deploy to other apps. The benefit is that you will only have to run build phase once.

Take a look at [Heroku Platform API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference), mainly at `slug` and `release` sections. You can use `slug info` to get url for compiled slug, `slug create` to upload compiled slug into your client app and `release create` to deploy it.

Also look into [Release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase), because you need a way to run migrations for each client when you deploy.