# What to do to run makemigrations/migrate on heroku when deploying changed models from github?

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-migrations

I have deployed  app from github repository  to  the heroku account of my customer as collaborator but this time  I had to add some new models.

However I realized that when I deploy my changes from github   heroku does not run makemigrations and migrate.

I I read some answers on stackoverflow and understood this is how it is supposed to be.

However my question is what should I do ? What is the best practise to deploy change models to heroku app. (I assume it is not deleting and recreating my app again since customer already has data there.)

(I am able to run makemigrations and migrate from the bash manually but when I have 30+ deployments it's a pain)

Comment: As has been said many many times here, you run makemigrations *locally* and commit the result, then run migrate on Heroku. (I don't understand your reference to 30 deployments.)

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Roseman. By 30 deployments I mean I have to deploy same code to 30 different cloud accounts. That means I have to run migrate for each of them .

Comment: That seems an odd thing to do. Are you sure you don't want a single deployment, scaled to 30 dynos?

Comment: Thats the plan .Any feedback welcome.Ideally it will be more than 30 eventually.Any feedback is welcome.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872949/mass-deploy-same-code-to-heroku-individual-accounts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the new feature on Heroku called "Release Phase": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase  It will allow you to run migrations during the deployment.  Just add whatever command you want to your Procfile, like this:

```
web: your_web_command
release: python manage.py migrate
```

The `release` command will run after your app is done building, and before it's launched.